# Отслеживание URL при клике по определенной ссылке

Tags: asp.net, url

У меня есть DataList, в который загружаются результаты поиска(url, title, description). Мне нужно узнать URL на который нажал пользователь из результатов поиска. Как это можно сделать?

```
<asp:Panel ID="panResults" runat="server" Height="236px">
    <p style="text-align: left" align="left"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal" Font-Bold="true" /></p>
    <asp:DataList ID="dlstResults" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkResultUrl" runat="server" 
                NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblResultUrl" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblResultSummay" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепишите событие OnClick для ссылок. в хэндлере клика смотрите NavigateUrl sender'а.

Comment: Макс Жуков, я пишу в Default.aspx, но события OnClick у него нет и просто оно не срабатывает. Почему я не могу обратится к HyperLink по ID. При наборе id его просто в нет в списке.
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkResultUrl" runat="server" OnClick="Link_Click"
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />

А вот это я пишу в code-behind
public void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

Comment: @skyboy, да, действительно, у гиперлинк нет онклмка. сорри. используйте asp:LinkButton вместо HyperLink. у линкбаттонов есть событие OnClick.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, вы не знаете почему я не могу обратится к HyperLink, если он вложен в DataList?

Comment: @skyboy, что лежит в dlstResults.Items?

Comment: @Макс Жуков, все я понял. Чтобы обратится к внутренним элементам DataList нужно подписаться на событие OnItemDataBound.

Comment: @skyboy, не забывайте закрывать вопрос.